# Can I use two ngForm in same component in angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, forms, angular4-forms

I am designing a settings page. I want to design two different form in the same component. one for profile update, one for password update. Is it possible to use two form element in the same component?

Comment: The answer is yes

Comment: @Huangism is it best practice or is there a better way?

Comment: If you need 2 form then do 2 forms, if you need 10 then do 10. What is your concern with more than 1 form?

Comment: Yes, please do this. Trying to share form groups across components is kind of difficult. If you start with two different forms it makes it easier to move the password logic to another component later.

Comment: I may have 1 settings_component which has 2 subcomponents one for profileUpdate, one for passwordUpdate. which one is better? having 2 subcomponents for 2 forms. or having one component for 2 forms?

Comment: I would lean toward one component per form for better encapsulation. But its a hard call for anyone from outside of the project that it not familiar with the details and requirements of your project.

Comment: ok. I have implemented it. It works fine. Does not affect each other. I have two forms on the same page(component). both have different submit buttons and other stuff. works well. thank for your help.... @Huangism

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can have multiple forms in one screen if it's needed.
Defined multiple reactive forms or template driven forms as needed. It's supported by Angular. 
If your two subcomponents do not have to do anything with each other, you can have two forms, one each in one component. if the forms are tied to each other at the time of initialization ( use data object etc) then you can have them in same component. No problem.. Which ever makes your life easier.